# Unity2D games , why my gameObject not destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Why my GameObject named "pipo" is not destroyed
This is my script:

> ```
> private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
> {
>     if (other.gameObject.name == "pipo")
>     {
>         Destroy(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Do you get any Error Messages

Comment: no , i not get it

Comment: yes , my game object has parent

Comment: try to see , i code again

Comment: Things to double check 1) This obj's collider is set to trigger 2) the other's colllider is not set to trigger  3) both objects have a `Rigidbody` component attached to them 4) this and the collider are attached to "pipo" and not it's parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your Code a little bit, first you should generally use `CompareTag()` which gives Error Messages when the given Tag doesn't exist.

After that you can add a check to see if the gameobject has a parent and depending on that destroy its parent or itself.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("pipo")){
    return;
    }

    if(other.gameObject.transform.parent) {
        Destroy (other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
 
    else {
        Destroy ( other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**When the object still doesn't get destroyed, you need to make sure that:**

1. The Gameobject you want to destroy has the tag called "pipo"
2. The GameObject where this script lies has IsTrigger enabled as well as a Collider
3. The "pip" GameObject has a Colllider and is not set to IsTrigger
4. Both objects have a Rigidbody component attached to them
5. Collider is attached to the "pipo" GameObject and not its parent